# Visual Basic Installer Setup set key outside the manufactor keynode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I want to create a Setup for a application written in Visual Basic with Visual Studio 2015. 
I use the Visual Basic Installer to create the Setup program. 
I need to set an regkey which has to be in
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows...` 
but the installer editor only shows posibility to enter key in
`HKLM\Software\[Manufacturer]...`

How can I insert my key?

Thank you!!

Comment: Why does your key need to be under some other product by some other publisher?

Comment: It needs to be there to change Windows settings. But I found the solution. You can just create existing nodes and the installer checks if they are available and if yes it only inserts the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

It is possible to add nodes which exist and the installed adds only what is not there.